# .htaccess redirect question

Tags: .htaccess

I want to do this:

Redirect only http://www.example.com/favfolder/ to http://www.example.com/

However requests for all files and subfolders within favfolder shouldn't be altered.

i.e., http://www.example.com/favfolder/* shouldn't get redirected.

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `RewriteRule` will redirect *favfolder* with optional trailing slash to the site webroot. Add the `R` flag if you want to set redirect headers (e.g. 301).

```
RewriteRule ^favfolder/?$ / [L]
```

Comment: Will it redirect http://www.example.com/favfolder (favfolder without /) properly as well?

Comment: Yes, note *with optional trailing slash* in my answer.

Comment: Thanks...this is the final answer then: `RewriteRule ^favfolder/?$ / [R=301,L]`